# Ito stochastic integral vs Skorohod integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm new in stochastic calculus and I'm confused about specific, but interesting topic. Skorohod integral is an extension of Ito integral for non-adapted processes, but how should I think about this type of processes closer to reality ? May I take, for example, shifted version of ordinary Bm $$X(t) = B(t+e),\quad e\gt0,$$ where $B(t)$ is adapted - ordinary brownian motion. And if you have in mind more "delicate" version of such processes, I kindly ask you to provide (I hope you have :)) )

Thanks!